# Given N sets of partitions, find a partition such that it satisfies a criterion

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics, set-partition

Given a collection of partitions $P_i$ of a set $X$,
find a partition $P$ such that each one of the sets in this partition is subset or equal to at most one set in each of $P_i$, i.e., for

$P_1$ = $\{s_11,s_12,s_13\}$,

$P_2$ = $\{s_21,s_22\}$,

and

$P$ = $\{s1,s2,s3\}$, where

$s1$ can be a subset of only one of $s_11$ or $s_12$ or $s_13$ but not more than one of them. Same goes for $s2$ and $s3$.

Similarly

$s1$ can be a subset of only of either $s_21$ or $s_22$ or but not both of them. Same goes for $s2$ and $s3$.

More formally $P$ is defined as ,

$\forall s_i \in P_i,$
and for $s \in A,$

If $Apar(s)=\{s_i\mid s\subseteq s_i\}$

$then$
$|Apar(s)|=1$

$Example 1:$

$X = \{e1,e2,e3,e4,e5\}$

$P_1 = \{\{e1,e2\},\{e3,e4\},\{e5\}\}$

$P_2 = \{\{e1\},\{e2,e3,e4\},\{e5\}\}$

$P_3 = \{\{e1,e2,e3,e4\},\{e5\}\}$

$P= \{\{e1\},\{e2\},\{e3,e4\},\{e5\}\}$

$Example 2:$

$X = \{e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7,e8,e9,e10,e11,e12\}$

$P_1 = \{\{e1,e2,e11,e12\},\{e3,e4,e5,e6\},\{e7,e8,e9,e10\}\}$

$P_2 = \{\{e1,e2,e3\},\{e4,e5,e6,e7,e8\},\{e9,e10,e11\},\{e12\}\}$

$P= \{\{e1,e2\},\{e3\},\{e4,e5,e6\},\{e7,e8\},\{e9,e10\},\{e11\},\{e12\}\}$

The problem is to find $min|P|$ as a function of $|X|$ and $|P_i|$.

It is trivial to see that the $max|P|$ is $|X|$

P.S. Forgive me if the mathematical description of the problem is not formal enough or if there are mistakes in it, I am not a mathematician.

Comment: Your terminology is off. The sets $S_i$ and $A$ are the *partitions*. The sets within the partition are just called sets (some may give them a special name, but there is no accepted convention). What you are is a partition $A$ that *refines* (or is a *refinement" of) each of the partitions $S_i$.

Comment: And please clarify, you want $|A|$ as a function of $|X|$ and $|S_i|$. But as your very next sentence indicates, you already realize that there is more than one such $A$. So its size cannot be expressed as a function, as there is more than one value for it. As you've noted, the largest such size is $|X|$. Do you want the minimal possible size of $A$?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks for the corrections, I have edited the question accordingly, please check if this makes sense now.